# Exercism JavasScript 2nd exercise: TypeError: (0 , _leap.isLeap) is not a function from

Tags: javascript

I am working on Exercism's JavaScript practice 2nd exercise to find out which years are leap year or not.

```
const isLeap = (year) => {

    if (year % 400 === 0) {
        return true
    } else if (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

console.log(isLeap(2015))
console.log(isLeap(2016))
console.log(isLeap(2100))
console.log(isLeap(2000))
console.log(isLeap(1800))
```

and when I run the test of the following:

```
import { isLeap } from './leap';

describe('A leap year', () => {
  test('year not divisible by 4: common year', () => {
    expect(isLeap(2015)).toBeFalsy();
  });

  xtest('year divisible by 4, not divisible by 100: leap year', () => {
    expect(isLeap(2016)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  xtest('year divisible by 100, not divisible by 400: common year', () => {
    expect(isLeap(2100)).toBeFalsy();
  });

 xtest('year divisible by 400: leap year', () => {
    expect(isLeap(2000)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  xtest('year divisible by 200, not divisible by 400: common year', () => {
    expect(isLeap(1800)).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

It gave an error message of 
      TypeError: (0 , _leap.isLeap) is not a function

I ran through my conditional logic, and everything seems to be fine. I declared isLeap function via fat arrow function, but the error saying it is not a function. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like the function isn't being exported correctly? Maybe `export const isLeap...` to make it a named export?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the actual logic, just about exporting/importing the function itself correctly.

Comment: What is *Exercism*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not exporting the function from the file. You need to:

```
export const isLeap = () => {...}
```

while declaring, or

```
export { isLeap }
```

after declaring

Comment: HA....  that's right... I forgot to export it. How did I miss that!!?   Thank you so much~